# Is it possible to send email to an address that contains latin unicode characters with cfmail?

Tags: email, unicode, coldfusion, cfmail

We need to be able to send an email with cfmail to an email address that contains a latin `a` with acute. I assume we'll eventually have to allow other Unicode characters too - a sample email address is `foobár@example.com`. ColdFusion throws an error on this email address, which is technically valid. Since the acute `a` is a UTF-8 character, and the default encoding for cfmail is UTF-8, I'm not sure what other settings I would need to enable to make this work. Is this possible?

The error I get is Attribute validation error for tag CFMAIL.

Detail: The value of the attribute to, which is currently foobár@example.com, is invalid.

Comment: @AlEverett attribute validation. Just updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, unicode characters are still invalid for emails. However, with [RFC5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322), they are trying to make changes to that.

Comment: @JonLim I've found various info online saying things about it being "recently accepted" so I am assuming it's an emerging issue we're going to have to find a workaround for. I'm using the jQuery Validate plugin which does allow them, I sort of assumed that if they were allowed there, then it was becoming more common. But perhaps not! I can always change the validation, but I wanted to see if there was a way to get it working in CF first.

Comment: @JonLim Did you mean [RFC 5336 SMTP Extension for Internationalized Email Addresses](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5336)?

Comment: +1 Hontvári's link. This is the standard that would one day give us Unicode usernames in e-mail addresses... if e-mail is still widely used by the time most deployed MTAs support it. Support today is very poor. Neither ColdFusion nor anything else can *reliably* send mail to foobár@example.com, so anyone using that address is going to find themselves without many people to talk to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm neither an I18N nor email expert but my understanding FWIW is that current systems don't generally support unicode in the **local part** of the email address, i.e. the mailbox name before the @. Local mail servers may support it and allow a name such as *foobár* internally, but if that person wants to receive mail from the outside world they will also need an ASCII alias such as *foobar*.

There is however a mechanism for supporting unicode in the **domain** portion of the address, which involves conversion to an ASCII representation called *punycode*. This means an address such as *foo@foobár.com* will be converted to *foo@xn--foobr-0qa.com* which current DNS and mail systems will accept.

It's possible to do this conversion in ColdFusion by using existing Java libraries. For more detail see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356460).